# Sony QX1 continuous shooting: fetch picture while shooting

Tags: android, sony-camera-api

I was wondering if it is possible to fetch the images for continuous shooting while the camera is still continuously taking pictures via the remote camera api?

This seems to be possible with PlayMemories in `"spd Priority cont."` mode. When using the api, the picture list seems to come in only when calling stop capture, even in `"spd Priority cont."` mode.

As an alternative, I tried just calling `actTakePicture` at fixed intervals, fetching the `2M` image. However every single URL returned for downloading the post view picture resulted in `FileNotFoundException`. (I have tested this method with both the QX10 and QX100 and no exceptions occurred) Is there a reason why this could be happening?